# Is it safe to store keys in TPM using Tpm2Lib?

Tags: c#, security, tpm, trusted-execution-environment

I was looking for a method to securely store values into a trusted execution environment and I found this library from Microsoft called Tpm2Lib.
I'm using the code below that is a actually working but I've some concerns about the security.
It is known that the data are stored securely in the TPM but, looking into the code, the AuthValue byte[] initialization is here, easy to be disassembled..
If an attacker disassemble my code he could easily write a software with the same AuthValue to get the secret from the TPM.. Am I right?

```
    public static AuthValue _authValue = new AuthValue(new byte[] { 22, 123, 22, 1, 33 });

            public static void SaveValueIntoTpm(int address, byte[] data, int length, AuthValue authValue)
    {
        Tpm2Device tpmDevice;
        if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            tpmDevice = new TbsDevice();
        }
        else
        {
            tpmDevice = new LinuxTpmDevice();
        }
        tpmDevice.Connect();

        var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);

        var ownerAuth = new AuthValue();
        TpmHandle nvHandle = TpmHandle.NV(address);

        tpm[ownerAuth]._AllowErrors().NvUndefineSpace(TpmHandle.RhOwner, nvHandle);

        AuthValue nvAuth = authValue;
        var nvPublic = new NvPublic(nvHandle, TpmAlgId.Sha1, NvAttr.Authwrite | NvAttr.Authread, new byte[0], (ushort)length);
        tpm[ownerAuth].NvDefineSpace(TpmHandle.RhOwner, nvAuth,nvPublic);

        tpm[nvAuth].NvWrite(nvHandle, nvHandle, data, 0);
        tpm.Dispose();
    }

    public static byte[] ReadValueFromTpm(int address, int length, AuthValue authValue)
    {
        Tpm2Device tpmDevice;
        if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            tpmDevice = new TbsDevice();
        }
        else
        {
            tpmDevice = new LinuxTpmDevice();
        }
        tpmDevice.Connect();
        var tpm = new Tpm2(tpmDevice);
        TpmHandle nvHandle = TpmHandle.NV(address);
        AuthValue nvAuth = authValue;
        byte[] newData = tpm[nvAuth].NvRead(nvHandle, nvHandle, (ushort)length, 0);
        tpm.Dispose();
        return newData;
    }
```

Comment: Can you use a password that is not static or maybe the state of the pcr registers?

Comment: I'm using that password as a shared symmetric password: I use it to authenticate all the http calls sent from 1 client to a server and all the http response of the server to the specific client. Different clients have different password. I wrote an HMAC authentication scheme to do that.. If I need to use non static password I've to change this schema.. maybe have you got some ideas?

Comment: Every key or password inside the binary can be found by an attacker, you could store it in the registry (windows) or in a config file. In both cases you must take care of the the file/key permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code you show doesn't follow best practices. I suggest you modify that code to take and validate input from the user for the auth value. You can also take the auth value as a command line parameter. GNU/Linux's [tpm2-tools](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools) allows this. See [tpm2_changeauth](https://tpm2-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/tpm2_changeauth.1/) for an example of this with tpm2-tools.

Keep in mind that Tpm2Lib is just a library, it's up to you to use it in a secure manner. The comments contain some good suggestions. In your situation, if you can keep your program running and don't have to re-run the program for every request, passing the auth value as a command line argument could work so long as you keep command line history safe. You could also prompt the user at the beginning and make sure you don't log/echo what's typed in. Otherwise, you're stuck with protecting a secure file and reading the auth value from that. If you add more details about the environment, there may be more options as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35754321)

Comment: @GabrielStancu, how is my answer "link only" when the only links I have are references/examples for all the text that I have written which is the actual answer?